# How to make circuit of a 32 X 32 matrix?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

I have a 32 X 32 matrix show in the picture below and I want to make a circuit for this matrix. Also in the picture below to the matrix picture I have written the each column in bra-ket notation to get the idea of operators required in the circuit by seeing the qubits.

[image: 32X32 matrix]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading your matrix correctly, it can be written as
$$
\cos(\theta)I+i\sin(\theta)Z\otimes X^{\otimes 4}.
$$
So, if I were you, I'd start by performing a rotation $R_z(2\theta)$ on the first qubit, creating
$$
(\cos(\theta)I+i\sin(\theta)Z)\otimes I,
$$
and then apply four controlled-nots, controlled off each of the other 4 qubits, and targetting the first qubit. That creates
$$
\cos(\theta)I+i\sin(\theta)Z^{\otimes 5}.
$$
You can then convert the $Z$s into $X$s using Hadamards. Overall, the circuit looks something like:
[image]

Comment: thanks @DaftWullie for answering my question if you don't mind can you please tell me what should I read for having a good command over matrix decomposition and circuit construction.

Comment: I would start with chapter 4 of Nielsen & Chuang, although, really, it's just about practice.

Comment: I think in the first equation [cos(θ) + i sin(θ) Z⊗X^⊗4].There is minus not the plus.  So the correct equation is [cos(θ) - i sin(θ)Z⊗^X⊗4]. I understand this mistake happen due to the poor quality picture. Now Is there any change in the first operator or just in the value of theta to change the sign? @DaftWullie

Comment: @vardhannegi You're probably right about the sign. As you say, just flip the sign of the rotation angle, $\theta\mapsto-\theta$.